# Can with this class prevent or detect possible SQL attacks?

Tags: php, mysql, get, filtering, sql-injection

I just wrote a simple PHP class that i think it will help me prevent or detect possible SQL attacks. I am not sure if that really works and thats why im posting it here to read your ideas and suggestions.

So lets start from the classic config.php file that creates a connection with the DB and selects a specific Database. I turned it into a class and it returns the connection link in the main page. Lets see:

```
<?php

class mysql_init
{

    public function initDb(){

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password");
        mysqli_select_db($con,"geneticDb");

        return $con;
    }
}

?>
```

So after this lets see the code of the main page safe.php. It has a simple example of fetching data from the DB through an Id that user gives with GET request.

```
<?php

require_once('filter.php');
require_once('config.php');

$connection = new mysql_init();
$con = $connection->initDb();

$safe = new filter($con,'GET');

$n_id = $_GET['noteId'];


$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT noteType FROM notes WHERE noteId = $n_id ");

if($data){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    echo $row["noteType"];
}

?>
```

As you can see i am including also and the filter.php which is a class that scans the GET or POST requests that user sends. If it will find something curious it takes the thread id of the session with the Database and shut it down. The truth is that is not finished and i mean that i will put it some futures to save some logs (of the attacker) to the database, and redirect him/her to another page informing him/her for the record.

```
<?php

class filter
{
    private $_activity = 0;

    public function __construct($sql_connection,$method){

        switch ($method) {
            case 'GET':
                $this->check_GET($sql_connection);
                break;

            case 'POST':
                $this->check_POST($sql_connection);
                break;

            case 'ALL':
                $this->check_POST($sql_connection);
                $this->check_GET($sql_connection);
                break;


            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }           
    }

    private function check_GET($con){

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
        {
            echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<br>".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."<br><br>";

            foreach($_GET as $index => $value)
            {                   
                if(preg_match('/\s/', $value))                              # no whitespaces
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/[\'"]/', $value))                           # no quotes
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/[\/\\\\]/', $value))                        # no slashes
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(and|or|null|not|if)/i', $value))           # no sqli boolean keywords
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(union|select|from|where)/i', $value))      # no sqli select keywords
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(group|order|having|limit)/i', $value))     # no sqli select keywords
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(into|file|case)/i', $value))               # no sqli operators
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(;|--|#|\/\*)/', $value))                   # no sqli comments
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(=|&|\|)/', $value))                        # no boolean operators
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(isset($this->_activity) && $this->_activity == 1){
                    echo "Something detected => ".$index." : ".$value."<br>";
                    $thread_id = mysqli_thread_id($con);
                    mysqli_kill($con, $thread_id);
                    $this->_activity = 0;
                }
            }
        } 
    }


    private function check_POST($con){

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
            echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<br>".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."<br><br>";

            foreach($_POST as $index => $value)
            {                   
                if(preg_match('/\s/', $value))                              # no whitespaces
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/[\'"]/', $value))                           # no quotes
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/[\/\\\\]/', $value))                        # no slashes
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(and|or|null|not|if)/i', $value))           # no sqli boolean keywords
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(union|select|from|where)/i', $value))      # no sqli select keywords
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(group|order|having|limit)/i', $value))     # no sqli select keywords
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(into|file|case)/i', $value))               # no sqli operators
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(;|--|#|\/\*)/', $value))                   # no sqli comments
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(preg_match('/(=|&|\|)/', $value))                        # no boolean operators
                    $this->_activity = 1;

                if(isset($this->_activity) && $this->_activity == 1){
                    echo "Something detected => ".$index." : ".$value."<br>";
                    $thread_id = mysqli_thread_id($con);
                    mysqli_kill($con, $thread_id);
                    $this->_activity = 0;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}

?>
```

So thats all for now. Do you think that this code is effective, or somehow it can be bypassed ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not going to like this answer... Testing. Extensive testing.

There can't be a simple yes/no answer to this.

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, then why aren't you using prepared statements and bind variables?

Comment: @Telexx There is a simple answer:  **NO**.  This class is not effective and can be bypassed.  To protect against SQL injection attacks, use prepared/parameterized queries.  Besides, what if I want to use the word `union` in some data I want to insert?

Comment: A couple of things you might try: PDO, prepared statements, I don't see encoding set, use php function `filter_var`

Comment: Ok. i ll try PDO with prepared statements but i want to ask if there is a way to alert with this method for someone who's trying to inject some code ?

Comment: There is no point in alerting with this method for anything. On a more or less popular website there will be thousands requests like this. you will just spam yourself with no purpose.

Comment: But if i wanna keep logs for any possible attack. What then?

Answer (score 1):

> Can with this class prevent or detect possible SQL attacks?

No.
It is inviable for the real life too.

Imagine a similar approach were used on this very site of Stack Overflow. Were you able to post your question, full of "dangerous" characters?

Comment: Yes can understand what you are say.Also i had to say that I am talking about numerical inputs.